# Not able to delete kubernetes ingress-object through kubernetes python client

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-python-client

I am getting this error while deleting the ingress objects.

```
Reason: Internal Server Error
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '161', 'Date': 'Wed, 14 Feb 2018 10:14:03 GMT'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"no kind \"Ingress\" is registered for version \"extensions/v1beta1\"","code":500}
```

And this is the code snippet I'm using to perform the delete...

```
try:
    resp = k8s_beta.read_namespaced_ingress(name=ing_name, namespace=namespace_name)
    resp1 = k8s_beta.delete_namespaced_ingress(
        name=resp['metadata']['name'],
        body=resp,
        namespace=namespace_name)
    print("Ingress deleted. status='%s'" % str(resp1.status))
except client.rest.ApiException:
    raise client.rest.ApiException
```

I ensured that the ingress-object actually exists with correct API versioning.Getting similar errors while trying to delete deployment objects!

Answer (score 0):

The param body needs to be an instance of client.V1DeleteOptions not the config of the ingress object.
`body = client.V1DeleteOptions()`

Answer (score 0):

Ingress can delete like this:

```py
from yaml import safe_load
from kubernetes.client import NetworkingV1Api
from kubernetes.config import new_client_from_config


KUBECONFIG="k8s config..."
temp_config_file = NamedTemporaryFile()
with open(temp_config_file.name, mode="w") as config_file:
    config_file.write(KUBECONFIG)

client = new_client_from_config(config_file=temp_config_file.name)
ingress_client = NetworkingV1Api(client)

ingress_client.delete_namespaced_ingress(name=job_name, namespace="default")
```

[documentation](https://github.com/pgajdos/kubernetes-client-python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/NetworkingV1Api.md#delete_namespaced_ingress)